# Is Android's Home Screen an entity that runs in foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton, android-background

When in an activity of an app and you press the Home button, the activity is moved from the foreground to the background in Android. However, is there a Home "activity" (entity) that gets brought to the foreground in its place? I am trying to understand more of the behind-the-scenes in Android -- any sources are greatly appreciated to learn more!

Comment: It's normal Activity

Comment: Interesting -- which "app" is it an activity of? Any sources to learn more about this process?

Comment: Some launcher app... It depends on which you got installed and selected as default... Basically if you press home button launcher app is started/bring to the foreground... It can be any activity with category android.intent.category.HOME

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation! Two follow-up questions I have are: 

(1) Is the "Home Screen" activity designated as the Launcher Activity of the app therefore? 

(2) Essentially, the Home button press is simply sending an Intent to the Home Screen Activity of the Launcher app. Correct?

Thank you again for your responses, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at this description of how to build a custom HOME screen of your own:

https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/cookbook